# Завершение программы или подпрограммы с помощью комбинации клавиш в Python

Tags: python, клавиатура, python-3.7

Есть код, который сохраняет изображение с камеры ноутбука с текущими датой и временем.В коде применяется создание окна с помощью библиотеки dlib. Этот код будет применён в программе написанной на kivy. Будет кнопка, которая будет запускать этот код. Необходимо завершить выполнение кода при нажатии другой кнопки или комбинации клавиш. Вместо цикла из 1000 итераций. В приоритете комбинацией клавиш, а то я так понимаю необходимо будет лезть в асинхронное программирование. Желательно, что бы программа так же завершалась по нажатию на крестик в правом верхнем углу созданного окна. Если я нажму этот крестик сейчас, то у меня продолжится выполнение программы, но окно исчезнет. Как это лучше сделать? Я даже не представляю как подойти к решению этого вопроса.

```
import cv2
import datetime
import dlib
import os
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)  # set Width
cap.set(4, 480)  # set Height

win1 = dlib.image_window()
for i in range(1000):
    win1.clear_overlay()
    ret, img = cap.read()
    win1.set_image(img)
    cv2.imwrite('img-jpg-color.jpg', img)  # output size: 109KB
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    os.rename('img-jpg-color.jpg', str(now.year) + str(now.month) + str(now.day) + '_' + 
    str(now.hour) + '_' + str(now.minute) + '_' + '(' + str(now.second) + ')' + str(now.microsecond) 
    + '.jpg')
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: не мешай киви и длиб.

Comment: для управления клавиатурой и\или мышью удобно использовать [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) в документации есть всё, что нужно.

Comment: ну, и если вы используете выведение на экран изображения с помощью cv2, то нажимая на окно вы можете использовать ```

while 1:

    # do something

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('2'): # если нажмёь любую кнопку и на 2, то будет чудо

        break
```
но это сработает, только если вы нажимаете на окно от cv2

Comment: [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372700/whats-0xff-for-in-cv2-waitkey1), в общем

Comment: @eri При чём тут это? Я конечно в этом вопросе не эксперт. Поясните пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема смешивания dlib и kivy? Ведь возникший у меня вопрос с этим никак не связан.

Comment: @Александр Благодарю, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @Александр Спасибо, теперь всё работает!

Comment: @Egor Shchukin, что вы использовали? pynput ? я бы из комментариев перенёс в ответ. так было бы удобнее

Comment: @Александр Добавил ответ. Переделал всё в cv2. Возможно излишки стоило из кода убрать. Пока оставлю так)

Comment: @Egor Shchukin я оставил ответ, с большим количеством информации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете использовать вместо 2 любой символ

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('2'):
    break
```

вот полезная информация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372700/whats-0xff-for-in-cv2-waitkey1

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey

также важно сказать, что если сделать cv2.waitKey(0), то это значит, ждать бесконечно долго, иначе цифра - количество миллисекунд, которое ждет функция, прежде чем прервать вернуть результат работы.

также можно использовать просто, тогда при нажатии на любую кнопку у вас остановится функция

```
if cv2.waitKey(1):
    break
```

все эти вещи должны использоваться в бесконечных циклах:

```
while 1:
    # do some
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('2'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как это делается в dlib, но получилось реализовать то же самое но с использованием cv2. При нажатии клавиши "2" окно закрывается и выполнение программы прекращается

```
import cv2
import datetime
import os
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)  # set Width
cap.set(4, 480)  # set Height
file = open("source jpg.txt", "w")

while(True):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video', img)
    cv2.imwrite('img-jpg-color.jpg', img)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    os.rename('img-jpg-color.jpg','_' + str(now.year) + str(now.month) + str(now.day) 
    + '_' + str(now.hour) + '_' + str(now.minute) + '_' + '(' + str(now.second) + ')' 
    + str(now.microsecond) + '.jpg')
    file.write(str(now.year) + str(now.month) + str(now.day) + '_' + str(now.hour) + 
    '_' + str(now.minute) + '_' + '(' + str(now.second) + ')' + str(now.microsecond) + 
    '.jpg' + '\n')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('2'):
        break
file.close()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: если вам понравился ответ, можете поставить ему upvote